# How do I improve this Menu code

Tags: php, html

I am using a function to spit out my main and sub menu's for me.  Basically I feed it a page ID and it gives me the menu with the menu item properly highlighted through CSS.

What I'm asking is: How do I improve this code (and others like it that I have laying around)? Lowering the amount of lines of code and decreasing repetition of code?  I know a Switch statement is faster than the old if/else conditional statements but I'm not sure how to highlight my HTML menu item if I use a switch.

The css class (class="sub_active_link") is responsible for highlighting the current menu item. A non-highlighted link is (class="sub_link").

I don't need the code re-written, just the concept or best practice for a situation like this.

Any ideas or direction is greatly appreciated and thanks for helping me become a more complete programmer.

```
function top_menu_logged_in_sub_menu($user, $page ='main')
{
    $sub_menu_html = '<div id="sub_nav"><ul>';
    if($page == 'main'){
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_L.gif" alt=""/></li>
                        <li class="sub_link_active"><span><a href="main.php">My Admin</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_R.gif" alt="" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    else{
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_L.gif" width="8" height="26" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link"><span><a href="main.php">My Admin</a></span></li>
                        <li ><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_R.gif" alt="" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    if($page == 'myProjects'){
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li ><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_L.gif" alt="" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link_active"><span><a href="myProjects.php">My Projects</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_R.gif" alt="" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    else{
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_L.gif" alt="" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link"><span><a href="myProjects.php">My Projects</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_R.gif" alt="" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    if($page == 'insertProject'){
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_L.gif" alt="" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link_active" ><span><a href="insertProject.php">Post a Project</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_R.gif" alt="" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    else{
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_L.gif" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link"><span><a href="insertProject.php">Post a Project</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_R.gif" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    if($page == 'myAccount'){
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_L.gif" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link_active" ><span><a href="myAccount.php">My Account</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_Hi_R.gif" /></li>
                    ';
    }
    else{
        $sub_menu_html.= '
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_L.gif" /></li>
                        <li class="sub_link"><span><a href="myAccount.php">My Account</a></span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_R.gif" /></li>
                    ';
    }

    $sub_menu_html.= '
            </ul>
                <div class="user_id">
                    Welcome, '.$user.'! &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="sign_out"><a href="http://www.example.org/login.php?action=logout">Sign Out</a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>
        </div>
    ';
    return $sub_menu_html;
}
```

Comment: Man, I bet your designer just loooves you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array, like this:

```
$pages=array('myAccount'=>'My Account', ...);
```

Then walk over it with foreach, compare the keys to the $page variable.
In the html code put some ternary operators:

```
'<li><img src="images/nav_2_lev_tab_'.($page==$key?'Hi_':'').'L.gif" /></li>'
```

This way you could use the values of the $pages array for the links text.

You'll find out the rest.